# Why did Nigamananda Paramahansa say Adi Shankaracharya's teachings were Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's path?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, chaitanya

One of the famous sayings of [Nigamananda Paramahansa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigamananda_Paramahansa) was:

> *''Shonkoracharyar moth Choitonyor poth''*

Which roughly translates as ''Shankaracharya's teachings are Chaitanya's path''.

However, the teachings of Adi Shankaracharya and Chaitanya Mahaprabhu seem to differ to a great extent. What is the logic and explanation behind this saying of Nigamananda Paramahansa? Did Nigamananda himself elaborate on this saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically he didn't mean Shankaracharya's teachings are Chaitanya's path. Its the error in 'wise translation'. He meant that ideally one should follow these 2 things for a full and complete spiritual progression. Knowledge is nothing without Bhakti. One should have the knowledge of Shankara and the Bhakti of Chaitanya. That's what he meant.

Comment: You could have just said this to me in the chat that day. Afterall you were the one who coined this saying to me.

Comment: I even explained to you why he said that. You still asked here, so I answered the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this as as the previous answerdoes not show any reference.

Narayani Devi, one very dear disciple of Paramahansa Nigamananda writes in her 'Sadguru and Guruvaad',Sarasvata Math,(page 46-47)

> The Sarasvata Math of Nigamananda is not a math of the Sahankara-panthis. He spoke of a perfect balance of Knowledge and Devotion. Yajnabalka says in Vrihadaranyaka: Brahma Satyam Jagat Mithya. Again the same rishi announces in the Ishopanishad : Ishavasyam idam sarvam". Similarly Nigamananda accepted both Netivada and Itivaada.The highest knowledge is obtained when the knowledge of the Gita is mixed with the Love of the Bhagavatam.